# Delphi - Change JavaScript from a loaded page in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi-2010, twebbrowser

How can I change JavaScript from a page already loaded in a TWebBrowser component?

I tried something like this:

```
var
  ElElem: IHTMLElement;
begin
  newJSfunction := 'function onclick(){alert("ok");}';
  ElElem := GetButtonFromBrowser;
  ElElem.onclick := newJSfunction;
  ElElem.click();
end;
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about, how to run a script fragment into current web browser, here is the solution:

```
function TMyWebBrowser.RunScript(const Fragment: string): Boolean;
var
  D2Ptr: IHTMLDocument2;
  Win2Ptr: IHTMLWindow2;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Supports(Document, IHTMLDocument2, D2Ptr) and 
     Supports(D2Ptr.parentWindow, IHTMLWindow2, Win2Ptr) then
    try
      Result := (Win2Ptr.execScript(Fragment, 'JavaScript') = S_OK);
    except
      // Failed to execute JS at runtime
    end;
end;
```